# Prove $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right) = \sin(x)$ from the unit circle definition

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry

I want to prove that

$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right) = \cos x \tag{1}$$

I can't use triangles and I need to prove it for all numbers.

Observation: By the $\cos$ identity:

$$\cos(a-b) = \cos a\cos b + \sin a\sin b$$
which is proven in a non-circular way, we have:

$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right) = \sin x$$

But I can't do the same, using $\sin(a-b)$ because I want to use $(1)$ to prove the $\sin(a-b)$ formula

Comment: nope, I need to prove $\sin(a-b)$ from the $\cos(a-b)$ formula, and it requires $\sin(\pi/2-x)$

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven I need $\sin(\pi/2-x)$ to prove $\sin(a-b)$ from $\cos(a-b)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking $a = \tfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $b = \tfrac{\pi}{2} - x$, we can use the same identity to get:
\begin{align*}
\cos(\tfrac{\pi}{2} - (\tfrac{\pi}{2} - x)) &= \cos(\tfrac{\pi}{2})\cos(\tfrac{\pi}{2} - x) + \sin(\tfrac{\pi}{2})\sin (\tfrac{\pi}{2} - x) \\
\cos(x) &= 0 \cdot \cos(\tfrac{\pi}{2} - x) + 1 \cdot\sin (\tfrac{\pi}{2} - x) \\
\cos(x) &= \sin (\tfrac{\pi}{2} - x) \\
\end{align*}
as desired.